# Modify a list using an integer

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out the following:
I take as input a list of lists and an integer N and the objective is to repeat the elements of the sublists N times by adding in front of each element a number in the range of N in increasing order.
For example as input we would receive:

```
>>> conversion([['GREEN', 'PURPLE'], ['RED']], 3)
[['GREEN0', 'GREEN1', 'GREEN2', 'PURPLE0', 'PURPLE1', 'PURPLE2'], ['RED0', 'RED1', 'RED2']]
```

My idea was creating an empty list, then adding each element of each sublist in this empty list. Then I would replace the elements with the same version and add range(N) at the end of it but in writing the code I either cannot separate the elements of sublists in the new list or cannot add or separate the different copies of the elements and the values in range(N)
I hope my explanation was clear and thank you for any help possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea of a new list is correct. Here is one possible solution.

```
def conversion(l, n):
   new_list = []
   for inner_list in l:
      new_list.append([])
      for word in inner_list:
         for i in range(n):
            new_list[-1].append(word + str(i))
   return new_list
```

One-liner alternative. (Just for fun):

```
def conversion(l, n):
   return [[word + str(i) for word in inner_list for i in range(n)] for inner_list in l ]
```

Comment: thank you very much, I was not sure how to incorporate the last for loop thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
def conversion(input_list, count):

    output_list = [
        [
            input_list[k][j] + str(i)
            for j in range(len(input_list[k]))
            for i in range(count)
        ]
        for k in range(len(input_list))
    ]
    return output_list
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to separate the two tasks into smaller functions to make it easier to understand. use `listrepeater()` to achieve the desired outcome of a list, and then run it in `nestedListRepeater()`

```
def listrepeater(l,multiplier):
    output = []
    for val in l:
       for i in range(multiplier):
          output.append(val + str(i))
          i+=1
    return output


def nestedListRepeater(inputlist,multiplier):
    outputlist = []
    for sublist in inputlist:
        outputlist.append(listrepeater(sublist,multiplier))    

    return outputlist

nestedListRepeater([['GREEN', 'PURPLE'], ['RED']],3)
```